# how to use the gps in google map in objective-c

Tags: iphone, gps

i want to use the gps in google map to automatically locate the user current location.
is mapkit framwork , the gps for iphone in objective-c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in viewDidLoad
write

```
self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
self.locationManager.delegate = self; // Tells the location manager to send updates to this object

self.mapView.delegate = self;
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

and then 
implement

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

delegate method newLocation will be user's Location

locationManager is CLLocationManager * locationManager;